# Avoiding redundancy with capistrano multistage extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have a deployment script for a production server I'm looking at the capistrano multistage extension to also add a staging server.

The multistage extension allows me to split my cap recipes into config/deploy/production.rb and config/deploy/staging.rb but much of the deployment script is identical and so it's redundant. Can I keep some of the definitions and tasks in a shared file? Anyone have experience with this?

UPDATE:

I found that duplicate tasks can be placed in deploy.rb. Only unique settings need to be placed in the files for the individual stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any identical variables and tasks should be defined in `deploy.rb`. Capistrano uses your deploy config first, and then the config for your stage. Variables defined inside stage configs will override those defined in `deploy.rb`.

In general, you should at least define a unique branch, hostname and roles for each stage.